# WkWebview redirect url issue to organisation login page

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, pingfederate

I am creating simple iOS application with Swift 4 using **WKWebView** and here **WKWebView** URL needs first to authenticate user using Microsoft way by entering email address and then it navigates to organisation login page. This is working fine on actual device browser, even on Simulator but **WKWebView** is not helping to redirect to organisation login page in actual device app. Does anyone encountered this type of issue with actual device. Please help or clue to fix this issue.

Implemented code:

```html
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = self.webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://<App URL>")!)
        self.webView.load(request)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors reported in the xcode console?

Comment: Hi jms, Sorry for late reply, actually I was trying to figure out the issue fix but looks like WKWebview has some issue to authenticate iOS device client certificate.