# Azure IDP block wkwebview auth request

Tags: azure, macos, wkwebview, idp

I am creating simple OSX application with Swift 5 using WKWebView and here WKWebView URL needs first to authenticate user using Microsoft way by entering email address and then it navigates to organisation login page.
My issue like this [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362023/wkwebview-redirect-url-issue-to-organisation-login-page).It just his problem with ios and my problem with osx.Does anyone encountered this type of issue with actual device. Please help or clue to fix this issue.

This is working fine on actual device browser, even on Simulator but WKWebView is not helping to redirect to organisation login page in actual device app.